# How to prevent css borders from floating to the top of parent div

Tags: html, css

I want my two "training-border" divs on my page to have their own bottom-borders.

```
    <div class="component-content">
    <div class="reporting-div">
        <div class = "training-border">
            <div class="dots width-75-left row">
                <div>
                    How to Train Your Dragon
                </div>
                <div class="cell circle-blue"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-text width-25-right">
                2 of 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "training-border">
            <div class="dots width-75-left row">
                <div>
                    How to Play Dumb in Poker
                </div>
                <div class="cell circle-blue"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-text width-25-right">
                2 of 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both use the following css styles:

```
.circle-blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.circle-gray {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cell {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 3px;
}
.width-75-left {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
.width-25-right {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.reporting-div {
    width: 100%;
}
.training-border{
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick dotted #ff0000;
}
.component-content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

What ends up happening, though, is that the border-bottom on the second div floats to the very top of the first div.  I want to accomplish the following:

1. Give each "training-border" div its own border-bottom without the border floating to the top of the first div
2. Do the above with minimal modification to the other .css classes

Here is the plnkr link.  Notice how the bottom border of the second div floats to the top of the first one:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WlsscFkmbuOocEnrz8IX?p=preview

Comment: Did you forget to clear a float?

Comment: Ah, that appears to be part of the reason.  Once the float is cleared, though, the "border-bottom" just ends up at the TOP of the div.  I need it at the bottom.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/QOIrypfw3LoeKQ8DQcsu?p=preview just cleared as Paulie says :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the float.

One method is:

```
.training-border{
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick dotted #ff0000;
    overflow: hidden; /* this */

}
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TtJrazJiKHrxdM1CftHd?p=preview)

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer once the required 10 minutes expires.